# Faster way to unmount the SD card?

Tags: external-sd

I unmount my SD card a lot, and I find it annoying to have to navigate through the settings app each time to safely unmount the SD card. I would like some way or some shortcut that can do this as quickly and as simply as possible.

I'm running Android 4.4.4 and I am rooted and using Xposed Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the app [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) to create a shortcut to the Storage settings activity of Settings app.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Tap on a particular entry and choose *Create* to create a shortcut on home screen.

Comment: You can try a more direct path using vdc command but I don't recommend it since after a remount from GUI it gives some error when an unmount is attempted, at least in my KitKat. `unmount`  seems not to be working appropriately either.

Comment: Can you please tell how to **unmount external SD card using the `vdc`** binary? I'm nowhere able to get a proper documentation for that command. And, `umount` command doesn't work as you said.

Comment: You can ask that as a separate question. If you don't want to do that, I suggest you look into the source code of vdc command-line tool. There you would not get to know the arguments vdc requires for a successful unmount and mount.

Comment: Excuse the typo "*not*" in the last line.

Answer (score 1):

The app [Shortcut Creator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alextern.shortcuthelper) works well. In the app, go to Shortcuts -> Settings -> Storage -> +

Maybe [Tile Shortcuts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tombayley.tileshortcuts) also works.